# Is $Var(x | x \le \tau)$ weakly increasing in $\tau$?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation

I am interested in $Var(x | x\le \tau)$ is increasing in $\tau$, where $x$ is some random variable with differentiable cdf. I can show that $E[x | x\le \tau]$ is increasing in $\tau$, which is intuitively obvious, by the following computation:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\tau}E[x\mid x\le\tau]=\frac{\partial}{\partial\tau}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\tau}\frac{xf(x)}{F(\tau)}dx\right)=\frac{f(\tau)}{F(\tau)}(\tau-E[x\mid x\le\tau]).
$$

In a similar vein, I tried the following:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial\tau}Var[x\mid x\le\tau] & =\frac{\partial}{\partial\tau}\left(E[x^{2}\mid x\le\tau]-E[x\mid x\le\tau]^{2}\right)\\
 & =\frac{\partial}{\partial\tau}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\tau}\frac{x^{2}f(x)}{F(\tau)}dx-(\int_{-\infty}^{\tau}\frac{x f(x)}{F(\tau)}dx)^{2}\right)\\
 & =\frac{f(\tau)}{F(\tau)}\left[\tau^{2}-E[x^{2}\mid x\le\tau]-2(E[x\mid x\le\tau]-\tau)\right]
\end{align*}
$$

Is this correct? I have a doubt because (i) a simulation result does not match with the analytical formula I have here (although the derivative of $E[x\mid x\le \tau]$ is verified by a simulation) and (ii) it is not clear if $Var[x\mid x\le \tau]$ is increasing in $\tau$ from the result, although a bunch of simulation suggests it is increasing.
If $Var(x\mid x\le \tau)$ is not increasing in general, under what conditions are they increasing? For example, what if $x$ is supported on positive values?

Comment: If $Y \sim Exp(1)$ and memoryless and $X=-Y$ then $Var(x \mid x\le \tau)=1$ i.e. constant for all $\tau$, and there will be other examples where it is decreasing for at least part of the distribution

Comment: Right, could you give me an example in which it is strictly decreasing? What kind of shape of distribution do I need to have a decreasing conditional variance?

Comment: Something like $F(x)=\exp(-\sqrt{-x})$ for $x \le 0$ would probably work

Comment: ... which I think has a conditional variance of $-4\tau+16\sqrt{-\tau}+20$ for $\tau \le 0$, strictly decreasing in $\tau$.    You could shift this (or most of it) into support on positive values and would get a strictly decreasing variance at least for $\tau$ in some interval, though I doubt it is possible for all $\tau$

Comment: It seems, intuitively, that $f(x\mid x\le\tau)\sim f(x)$ for $\tau\to\infty$ (bec. there's no new information in the proposition "$x\le\infty$"). This would imply that your two equations can't hold unless $\tau^kf(\tau)\to 0$ for $k=1,2$ respectively.

Comment: @Henry Interesting, do you have an intuition for the result? How do you come up with the example?

Comment: @r.e.s. I understand that $f(x\mid x\le \tau)\sim f(x)$ for large $\tau$, but what does it imply that we need $\tau^k f(\tau)\to 0$ as $\tau$ goes to the upper bound of the support? My second equation is just a definition and I think it is valid as long as the conditional variance exists. The third equation is from Leibnitz rule.

Comment: When I tried with a discrete version on the sequence $1,10,11,11,11,11$, I got that the conditional variance up to 11 was less than the conditional variance up to 10.  So, if you made narrow enough bump functions to approximate that distribution, then the function must be decreasing somewhere between 10 and 11.

Comment: Because, if there is no dependence on $\tau$, then the derivatives w.r.t. $\tau$ must vanish.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Interesting! Although it is not the approximation of the sequence you game, I tried Beta(2, 100), which has a pdf of "bump and stabilize", but in this case it doesn't seem to be decreasing. I wonder what is the difference between the discrete case and this beta case

Comment: I started to think that this problem is not obvious and I found this article (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165176596008749). Apparently under some regularity condition it is increasing in tau.

Comment: @user789100 My initial comment gave an example $F(x)=\exp(x)$ with $x \le 0$ where the conditional variance was constant, related to the memorylessness of the exponential distribution.  So my later example wanted a cdf which  stretched the probability to get the desired result and $F(x)=\exp(-\sqrt{-x})$ was the first case I thought of and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it is possible for the conditional variance $\text{Var}(X \mid X \le \tau) $ to be strictly decreasing for all $\tau$ but it is certainly possible to be weakly decreasing for all $\tau$ and strictly decreasing for some $\tau$.

An alternative formulation is to take $Y=-X$ and $t=-\tau$ and ask about  $\text{Var}(Y \mid Y \ge t)$ as a function of $t$.

If $Y$ has an exponential distribution with rate $\lambda$ then $\text{Var}(Y \mid Y \ge t)$ is constant $\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$ for all $t$: this is a direct consequence of the memoryless property of the exponential distribution.  So some adjustment to $Y$ should get the desired property.

One such is $Z=Y^2$, for example setting $\lambda=1$ and with CDF $F_Z(z) = 1-e^{-\sqrt{z}}$ and density $f_Z(z) = \frac{e^{-\sqrt{z}}}{2\sqrt{z}}$ when $z \ge 0$. You then get

- $\mathbb E[Z \mid Z \ge t] = t+2 \sqrt{t}+2$
- $\text{Var}(Z \mid Z \ge t) = 4t+16 \sqrt{t}+20$

when $t \ge 0$, while $\mathbb E[Z \mid Z \ge t] = \mathbb E[Z]=2$ and  $\text{Var}(Z \mid Z \ge t) = \text{Var}(Z)=20$ when $t \le 0$.  These are increasing functions of $t$.

We just reverse the signs to answer your question. If $X$ has CDF $F_X(x) = e^{-\sqrt{-x}}$ and density $f_X(x) = \frac{e^{-\sqrt{-x}}}{2\sqrt{-x}}$ for $x \le 0$ then $\text{Var}(X \mid X \le \tau) = -4\tau+16 \sqrt{-\tau}+20$ for $\tau\le 0$, which is a decreasing function of $\tau$.

If you want want an example to be strictly decreasing for some positive $\tau$, just shift $X$, for example with CDF $F_X(x) = e^{-\sqrt{5-x}}$ when $x \le 5$ the conditional variance will still be decreasing, and strictly decreasing for $\tau \le 5$.